# CKEDITOR and PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for all my textarea in a web based game, when i type into the textarea and click the submit button it saves to my database but the database also includes the tags like `<p>` and `<b>`.

How could I remove them?

Comment: You could try [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: what about `strip_tags`?

Comment: Ckeditor is for saving HTML, so it is saving HTML in your DB.

Comment: still can't understand strip_tags function

Comment: see this one http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ck-editor is for saving HTML, so it is saving it in your DB. If you want to save only the text then there is no need to use ck-editor, because it is for formatted text. However if you want to use it, then the correct way is to pass through the function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php  before saving to database and when retrieve it, pass through the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php and then put it in ckeditor then you can edit it or put where you are displaying it in a page.

And if you want to strip tags then use this function php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php  but in this case you will lose the text format.

Comment: well i am using this for a news system because ckeditor allows me to add images and other stuff to it..

Comment: Yes what I am explains in the first paragraph is valid for you. Because you need to save format text having images, bold text, color etc for news, so use the above method to do it. I also done it for my website.